# Alternatives to Google Earth that can consume KMZ

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, google, maps

I'm trying to eliminate Google software from my OS X experience.

I would like to eliminate Google Earth. Are there OS X tools that can consume or work with KMZ files? Are there good online tools that can work with these files? I'm keen to visualise points of interest on maps, but while OS X Maps provides a great user experience, it does not seem to import or show externally provided data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Marble](https://marble.kde.org/) looks like a good replacement. It's free, open source, and says it supports KML files.
I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a great experience with [MapPlus](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/map-plus/id438868200) using also KMZ with raster overlay.